# Python pandas to read an Excel file with more than one row headers

Tags: python, pandas

Like the data here, if I have more than one header, how can we read the specific column that I want, thanks!

```
       machine A       A       B
       date    12-01  12-02   12-01
       number  #1      #2      #2
              0.223   0.224   0.226
              0.333   0.444   0.234
              0.234   0.124   0.456
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the xs function:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html

For exemple

```
print(df.xs('A', level='machine', axis=1))
```

Or

```
print(df.xs('#1', level='number', axis=1))
```